# Select a list of set columns AND other columns depending on their name/regex (Spark SQL Java)

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I have a list of columns that I need to select. I have the field names for each column in this list, so it is easy to select.

```
public Column[] getSelectColumns()
{
        return new Column[]{
                col("name"),
                col("value"),
                col("date"),
        }
}

final Dataset<Row> testDf = df.select(getSelectColumns());
```

However, I want to combine this with other columns where I do not have their exact field names. These other columns only share a similar pattern in their names, such as `weather_id`, `house_id`, `person_id`. They all end in "_id". Each row may or may not have these "_id" columns. The "_id" columns are dynamic so I cannot hardcode them in like I do in `getSelectColumns()`.

Am I able to select columns based on the "_id" pattern (like using regex)? And if I can, how do I combine that with my regular select? So that my end result `Dataset<Row>` has all the columns I need.

Answer (score 0):

Spark has a `colRegex` function which can be use to select columns based on `regex`.

Something like this :

`` df.select(df.colRegex("`^.*name*`")).show() ``

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dataset#colRegex(String)`

```
df.colRegex("`.*_id`")
```

This should work.
I didn't test that but you can change your code to:

```
Dataset<Row> df = ...;
Column[] cols = new Column[]{
     functions.col("name"),
     functions.col("value"),
     functions.col("date"),
     df.colRegex("`.*_id`")
    };
final Dataset<Row> testDf = df.select(getSelectColumns());
```

Alternativaly, you could use `df.columns()` to get all the column names, then apply a regular java regex to filter out only the columns you need and select the columns from there.

See more:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#colRegex-java.lang.String-